# Modfying class instance fields using a method with key-object parameters

Tags: java, instance, field

This has been an issue I've been running into quite a bit lately. I know a sort of hack to make it work, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but it seems like it's the only way short of reflection, which appears to be universally discouraged against.

What I'm trying to do: I have class instances that I want to be able to modify through user input (Strings). So, for example:

```
public class Apple
{

   private String color; //Color of the apple
   private float cost; //Cost of the apple
   private double radius; //Radius of the apple

   public Apple()
   {
      this.color = "";
      this.cost = 0;
      this.radius = 0;
   }

   //The method I am concerned/talking about
   public void setValue(String key, Object value)
   {
      if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("color"))
      {
         this.color = (String)value;
      }
      else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("cost"))
      {
         this.cost= (float)value;
      }
      else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("radius"))
      {
         this.radius = (double)value;
      }
   }
}
```

Is this considered bad form? I have a key (String) from a user to identify the property/field they want to modify, and then I have another String (value) to indicate the value they want to change it to. I'm sure I could use reflection, but

A) I've heard its bad form and frowned upon

B) It requires perfect accuracy in terms of variable names. So if I have 'appleColor', and the user puts 'applecolor', it won't work. Or, if I have 'applecolor' and I want the user to just be able to put in 'color', etc.

I'm wondering if there is a more structured/object oriented/useful way to do this. I thought about perhaps having each class that requires 'setValue()' to have a HashMap that matches a property/field to it's string key, but I'm not sure if that should be achieved through a method such as 'getHashMap()' that returns a hashmap with

hashMap.put("color", color)... or what.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just pointing me in the direction of a design pattern that handles this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the program to instinctively know what property to map to? That's not feasible. If you don't want to use reflection libraries, do your own and work the key the way you want.

Compare the keys ignoring the case and using the contains I guess.

Here is an algorythm that can help you, change it at your taste:

```
public static T Cast<T>(this Object myobj)
    {
        Type objectType = myobj.GetType();
        Type target = typeof(T);
        var x = Activator.CreateInstance(target, false);
        var z = from source in objectType.GetMembers().ToList() where source.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property select source;
        var d = from source in target.GetMembers().ToList() where source.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property select source;
        List<MemberInfo> members = d.Where(memberInfo => d.Select(c => c.Name).ToList().Contains(memberInfo.Name)).ToList();
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
        object value;
        foreach (var memberInfo in members)
        {
            propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(memberInfo.Name);
            PropertyInfo _prop = myobj.GetType().GetProperty(memberInfo.Name);
            if (_prop != null)
            {
                value = _prop.GetValue(myobj, null);
                try
                {
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(x, value, null);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        return (T)x;
    }
```

Comment: That's because it is. He didn't specify the language and I read it in C#.

Comment: The question is tagged java. Not that it makes a big difference.